# String List value is different in javascript and java action file

Tags: javascript, java, string, arraylist, var

Good day,

In my java action file, I have a list:

```
 protected ArrayList< String > deletedCorpRegisteredAccountRefNo = new ArrayList< String >( );
```

And then I put in some data inside this ArrayList, and print it out:

```
   System.out.println( "deletedCorpRegisteredAccountRefNo : "+
                deletedCorpRegisteredAccountRefNo );
```

And the result display correctly:

```
deletedCorpRegisteredAccountRefNo : [0000000000000234324, 0000000000015422629]
```

Then I go to my jsp and my javaScript function, I tried to assign this ArrayList value to a var call `refNoList`, and print out:

```
var refNoList = ${actionBean.deletedCorpRegisteredAccountRefNo};
console.log(refNoList);
```

I am expected I will see my browser console will print out something like what I see in Java System.out.println(), but I get another result:

```
[80084, 15422629]
```

The `15422629` is still acceptable, because maybe JavaScript auto trim the `0`. But not understand why `0000000000000234324` will become `80084`, this is totally different.

I try to google to find what is the root cause, but fail to get it, I think I am asking the wrong question in Google.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a JavaScript number starts with zero, it can be interpreted as an *octal value*. And

```
var x = 0234324;
console.log(x);
```

this writes out `80084`, because in decimal, this is the same value, as `234324` in octal.

You need to trim the trailing zeroes from the strings, and it will work as you want it to.

---

#### Other number definitions

In JavaScript the numbers can be interpreted as binary, octal, decimal or hexadecimal. Here a little list of different literals:

```
123         - normal decimal
0123        - octal: decimal value is 83
0x123       - hexadecimal: decimal value is 291
0o123       - octal: decimal value is 123
0b101       - binary: decimal value is 5
```

The problem with the second example (`0123`) is that it is only interpreted as octal when it is possible. E.g. `09123` and `081` will be interpreted as decimal. Moral of the story, you should not depend on this behaviour, if you need an octal, use `0o` explicitely, if you need decimals, trim those zeroes.

---

#### Fixing the issue

To parse the number as a decimal, no matter what, you can simply give the *radix* value as a parameter to `parseInt(number, radix)`:

```
var x = "000000123";
console.log(parseInt(x, 10)); // prints out 123
```

Comment: Nice explanation, Btw, do you have any idea or suggestion to overcome my problem?

Comment: You can use `parseInt(number, 10);`